# connect() to unix:/home/glenn/blog.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream

Tags: django, nginx, ubuntu-22.04

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-22-04#introduction) to deploy my django project using gunicorn  on an ubuntu 22.04 server, and I think my configuration file is okay. However when I try to go to my Ip address on the server I get a 502 getway error. When I check the error log, I get the following output:

> 2022/08/09 22:05:36 [crit] 7960#7960: *5 connect() to unix:/home/glenn/blog.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 197.231.183.74, server                                                                                  : 67.205.168.227, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/glenn/blog.s                                                                                  ock:/", host: "67.205.168.227"

I have followed [the documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-22-04#troubleshooting-nginx-and-gunicorn) to check for possible troubleshooting guides, and I have been advised to check for my permissions. On doing so, I get the following error log

```
drwxr-xr-x root  root     /
drwxr-xr-x root  root     home
drwxr-x--- glenn glenn    glenn
srwxrwxrwx glenn www-data blog.sock
```

So does anyone know of a specific command I can use to edit the permissions? Or how I can edit my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/blog` file to change the permissions

here is how my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/blog` file looks like

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 67.205.168.227;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
                root /home/glenn/blog;
        }

        location /media/ {
                root /home/glenn/blog;
     }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/glenn/blog.sock;
        }
}
```

Here is my gunicorn.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires = gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=glenn
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/glenn/blog
ExecStart=/home/glenn/blog/env/bin/gunicorn \
        --access-logfile - \
        --workers 3 \
        --bind unix:/home/glenn/blog.sock \
        blog.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: What user is running Nginx?

Comment: I have created a user called glenn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I discovered that the problem is that I was running debug as True (You cannot run with debug on while in production)
And then I also changed the read/write permissions since the user needs to have access to all the files within the directory, by using the command `chmod og+x /home/lamnk`